# p-listbox: [filter]="true "not filtering first element in the list

Tags: javascript, angular, filtering, primeng

I am using primeng v9.1.2. Applying filter property to `p-listbox` tag is not filtering the first element in the list.
Code for the listbox is

```
<p-listbox [options]="displayList" name="text" [metaKeySelection]="false" [checkbox]="true"
                                                       [filter]="true" [multiple]="true" optionLabel="text" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'250px'}"
                                                       [style]="{'width':'100%'}">
      <ng-template let-field>
         <div>
             <div>{{field.text}}</div>
         </div>
      </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

For example if

```js
    displayList = [
        {text: "sam"},
        {text: "curran"},
        {text: "vladi"},
        {text: "burman"},
        {text: "teach"}
    ];
```

The text `"sam"` can be seen everytime if you search for any text.